# What are the benefits of visiting temples?

Tags: temple

What are the benefits, either spiritual or material, mental or physical?

EDIT: This is a more specific question asking specifically about the benefits.

Comment: Temples are not for praying. Temples are energy points as they are constructed upon certain prescribed regulations - directions, certain places etc...Ex: Pazhani malai Murugan temple has Mars planet rays falling over there. So when you visit a temple such as Pazhani Murugan, Sabarimala, Vaithishvaran, without your awarness, you get fresh energy which later changes your Karma.

Comment: Priests are benefitted more than worshippers